Обновился до fedora 40. В наутилусе текст исчезает при потере фокуса
Fedora 40, гном. В некоторых окнах текст изначально отсутствует или исчезает при потере фокуса. Например, в наутилусе остаются только иконки папок без подписей к ним. Если погонять по окну курсором мыши,то подписи к папкам восстанавливаются. Есть и другие приложения с такими "спецэффектами" - магазин приложений, калькулятор, настройки системы...
На ум пришло только попробовать запретить wayland - безрезультатно.
Карта NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER
Драйвер NVIDIA 470.239.06 - он может быть причиной?

А чего драйвер такой старый-то, эта видеокарта ведь может работать с самым свежим драйвером

Только что обновил до 470.256.02 - самый свежий из рпмфьюжен. Думаю, может наоборот, к более старым откатится. Кстати, с nouveau проблемы нет, прверил. но с ним всё весьма уныло работает.

Самый свежий — это 550.90.07. Если в вашей федоре его почему-то нет, значит с вашей федорой что-то не так, потому что в репозитории этот драйвер явно есть https://fedora.pkgs.org/40/rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-x86_64/akmod-nvidia-550.90.07-1.fc40.x86_64.rpm.html

Два года сижу на opensource-версии драйвера от Nvidia полет нормальный. Для чего вам нужен проприетарный?

@andreymal у него есть какие-то редко-верстные зависимости. Так бывает, когда какие-то пакеты ставишь из сторонних репозиториев, а потом, например, из-за какого-нибудь требуемого модуля к python 3.10 не может обновиться вся система.

@DiD «Для чего вам нужен проприетарный?» — ну например для производительности?) Ну или хотя бы просто для нормальной работы — когда я пытался запускать Counter-Strike 2 на nouveau, система просто уходила в kernel panic ¯\(ツ)/¯

Та же самая проблема, Fedora 40, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti, драйвера недавно обновились, разницы никакой не произошло. Миниатюры содержимого файлов не грузятся, текст в уведомлениях, меню и в проводнике обычно отсутствует, появляясь (иногда) при наведении. Ещё в системном журнале несколько раз в секунду прописывается
Translated default ''24h'' for key 'clock-format' in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' is outside of valid range — о такой проблеме тоже сообщают в последнее время на разных языках. Возможно, они не связаны, а возможно связаны. Это лучше было конечно писать в комментарии, а н

@DiD очень лагает гном на nouveau. Фризит иногда

clock-format я пофиксил кстати. Перезаписал без кавычек параметр

Да я вообще nouveau не имел в виду, я имел в виду как модули ядра ставить.... но там не все видеокарты это поддерживают. "open kernel modules can be used on any Turing or later GPU".  Вот тут список видеокарт в таблице

Починить этот эффект можно удалив поддержку egl у проприетарного драйвера. В дебе у меня пакет libnvidia-eglcore . gtk начинает рендериться в софте и текст отображается стабильнее. Но осталась проблема с диалогом "открыть" в телеграме.

Спасибо! Установил akmod-nvidia 550.90.07 из rpmfusion, "спецэффекты" пропали.
Попутно выяснил, что не все зеркала rpmfusion имеют одинаковое содержимое (зеркало, прописанное у меня, не содержало этого пакета), чем весьма озадачен.
